# Python default (mutable) parameter initialization style

Tags: python, styles

Let's have a function `make_sandwich` that takes a list of `ingredients` which has a default value of `['ham', 'ham', 'bacon', 'ham']`

```
def make_sandwich(ingredients=['ham', 'ham', 'bacon', 'ham']):
    print("Making a sandwich with ", ingredients)
```

However, since this default value is susceptible to [this python "mutable default argument" <s>bug</s> feature](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments), we should use an immutable instead like this:

```
def make_sandwich(ingredients=None):
    # initialized ingredients here
    print("Making a sandwich with ", ingredients)
```

So here's the question. There're two ways that I am aware of to do this, but I am not sure which one is considered a better practice.

The first one:

```
if not ingredients:
    ingredients = ['ham', 'ham', 'bacon', 'ham']
```

The second one:

```
ingredients = ingredients or ['ham', 'ham', 'bacon', 'ham']
```

Personally I use the second one more often. Sometimes, I even inline that if the argument is used only once. e.g.

`print("Making a sandwich with ", ingredients or ['ham', 'ham', 'bacon', 'ham'])`

Is there any solid reason to prefer one over the others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of them is actually the right way to do. What if you want to pass an empty list of ingredients?

A better solution would be

```
ingredients = ['ham', 'bacon', 'ham'] if ingredients is None else ingredients
```

Comment: good point! I guess the other solution of mine suffers from the same reason.

Comment: Indeed, they have the exact same behavior and are just a matter of preference. Don't forget to select the answer if you consider it answers your question the best.

Answer (score 1):

a matter of personal style.  you could also do

```
ingredients = ingredients if ingredients else ['ham', 'ham', 'bacon', 'ham']
```

just depends on who will be reading your code.
personally i'm fine with your second

```
ingredients = ingredients or ['ham', 'ham', 'bacon', 'ham']
```